# How to connect Android Studio to Mysql via php on a FTP client(Winscp) NO XAMPP NO WAMP

Tags: android, mysql, android-studio

How to connect Android Studio to Mysql via php on a FTP client(Winscp) NO XAMPP NO WAMP. I managed to follow a tutorial and make a login/sign up android app but right now I want to make it work via Mysql Workbench and php files that are stored on a FTP (Winscp to be specific). I dont want to hear aboyt XAMPP OR WAMPP, I do manage to do that

```
package com.example.miracol;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Register extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextInputEditText textInputEditTextName,textInputEditTextEmail, textInputEditTextPassword;
    Button buttonSubmit;
    String name, email, password;
    TextView textViewError;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
        textInputEditTextName = findViewById(R.id.name);
        textInputEditTextEmail = findViewById(R.id.email);
        textInputEditTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.password);
        textViewError = findViewById(R.id.error);
        buttonSubmit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.loading);
        buttonSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                name = String.valueOf(textInputEditTextName.getText());
                email = String.valueOf(textInputEditTextEmail.getText());
                password = String.valueOf(textInputEditTextPassword.getText());


                RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
                String url ="http://192.168.38.102/login-registration-android/register.php";

                StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                        new Response.Listener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(String response) {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);


                            }
                        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        textViewError.setText(error.getLocalizedMessage());
                        textViewError.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    }
                }){
                    protected Map<String, String> getParams(){
                        Map<String, String> paramV = new HashMap<>();
                        paramV.put("name", name);
                        paramV.put("email", email);
                        paramV.put("password", password);

                        return paramV;
                    }
                };
                queue.add(stringRequest);
            }
        });



    }
}
```

From what Ive gathered it has to do with HTTP request somewhere around String url ="http://reggiedex.infoapp.cf/register.php"; ? As it is it loads forever its unable to read the register.php file present on the FTP (winscp) its being stuck omn a loop and loads forever? PLease tell what Im doing wrong or what other small- medium appps on the stores are manaagin to do it? (im assuming theyre not using xampp and wampp)

Comment: Do you have a webserver insralled with php configured on the server where you have the php files? If not, then there is nothing to run php with.

Comment: `How to connect Android Studio to Mysql....` I think that you want your Android app to do that. Not Android Studio.